# Show truncated text on touch

Tags: css, mobile, truncated

As we know we could truncate text with CSS and "untruncate it this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
.one-long-line {
max-width:400px;
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.one-long-line:hover {
overflow:visible;
}
</style>
```

I used this to cut a long H1 in mobile view, but I want the user to be able to see the full header. Because hover doesn't work on mobile I wonder if something similar could be coded where the user touches the header and of course what this code should be.
Thanks

Comment: `tabindex` plus `:focus` …?

Comment: Added:the Javascript and 'id="my-span" tabindex="0"' to the H1 tag but unfortunately this didn't work (truncation did not succeed leave alone the desired toggle)

Answer (score 0):

Works with :active

```
.overflow-tip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.overflow-tip:active, .overflow-tip:hover {
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

See demo [here](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/mAPkWP)